# keyboard shortcut for object library's search field in xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode5

Is there a keyboard shortcut that will directly put my cursor on the object library's search field. Whenever I want to add new view i drag my mouse to the bottom right and click on the search field to search for objects like "button" "label" instead i am looking for a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update for Xcode 10

Shortcuts from the keyboard for opening the Object Library is:

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

---

### Old

In object Library You can set your focus Direct to object, using just press particular key for object from keyboard,

Sect focus to Object Library **⌃⌥⌘ 3**   / <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> -<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +3

If you want UIButton just press `B` and focus is on UIButton.

You not need to search every time in searchbar.

**Or**

You can change GridView of Object Library so you can see more controls at time,
[image]

Than you will see like

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. i also found that i can customize my shortcuts in preferences. so now i configured it to suit me.

Answer (score 29):

**Instructions for Xcode 10:**

Shortcuts from the keyboard for opening the Object Library is:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Or from Xcode:

View -> Libraries -> Show Library

like the following image:

[image]

Comment: this is even better, view the shortcut from the menu. Cant go wrong

Answer (score 3):

there's a simpler shortcut than the accepted answer.

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Something extra that I've just found out. Tapping enter after selecting an object from the object library pane will get it added to the storyboard, inside the currently selected view.

Comment: cmd + option + L takes to the panel but not directly to the object library in case some other tab is selected. ⌃⌥⌘ 3 / Command + Option -Ctrl +3 works as expected. hence just upvoted and not changing the best answer

Comment: good to know. Also I just wanted to share and am not expecting change of best answer so that's ok as well

Answer (score 2):

## All the Instruction of using the Library for xCode versions 10 and above

1. If You have your cursor on storyboard you'll see Object Library and can access with shortcut

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

[image]

2. If You have your cursor on your Class file you'll see Code Library and short will be the same

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

[image]

3. Media Library can be accessed from everywhere using the shortcut

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

[image]

or by holding the left mouse click over the library icon

[image]

I hope you have all the answers you were looking for, **Have a great day**!

Answer (score 1):

from Xcode 10:

```
    ⇧⌘L Objects (cursor in storyboard), Snippets (cursor in assistant editor)  
    ⇧⌘M Media library 

     esc to escape this pop overs. 

shift command L : library objects/ code snippets
shift command M : media library
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ordinary Way:**

1. Select Storyboard
2. Select ViewController where you need to add controls
3. Select the top right corner + button

[image]

**Shortcut Way:**

You need to use simply: **Cmd + Shift + L**

[image]

Comment: We have to use shortcut keys to increase our day-to-day productivity.